# when is docker volume available using docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm relatively new to Docker. I have a docker-compose.yml file that creates a volume. In one of my Dockerfiles I check to see the volume is created by listing the volume's contents. I get an error saying the volume doesn't exist. When does a volume actually become available when using docker compose?

Here's my docker-compse.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app-api:
    image: api-dev
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./app-api/Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ../library:/app/library
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
```

I also need to have the volume available when creating my container because I use it in my dotnet restore command.

Here my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS api-env

#list volume contents
RUN ls -al /app/library

WORKDIR /app/app-api

COPY ./app-api/*.csproj .

#need to have volume created before this command
RUN dotnet restore --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --source /app/library

#copies all files into current directory
COPY ./app-api/. .
RUN dotnet run Api.csproj
EXPOSE 5000
RUN echo "'dotnet running'"
```

I thought by adding `-volumes: ....` to docker-compose.yml it automatically creates the volume. Do I still need to add a create volume command in my Dockerfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR:

- The commands you give in `RUN` are executed before mounting volumes.
- The `CMD` will be executed **after** mounting the volumes.

### Longer answer

The Dockerfile is used when building an image of the container. The image will then be used in a `docker-compose.yml` file to start up a container, to which a volume will be connected. The `RUN` command you are executing is executed when the image is built, so it will not have access to the volume.

You would normally issue a set of `RUN` commands, which would prepare the container image. Finally, you would define a `CMD` command, which would tell what program should be executed when a container starts, based on this image.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You're saying I should issue RUN commands in the docker compose before the container starts up?

Comment: No. The Dockerfile is where you use RUN commands. You use them to prepare the image, e.g. install additional software packages, etc. If you need to do some modifications based on your source code - probably the best way will be to COPY the data needed into the image.